ssms 20.1 tasks/generate scripts fails
running ssms 20.2, selecting database, right-click, choosing tasks then generate scripts.  I select tables I want scripted and get a message that script generation failed and I am instructed to click help for known solutions.  clicking help gets nothing.
I tried all the solutions I could find on the web, e.g.  running ssms as admin, selecting fewer tables, different servers. This worked just a week ago!

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

It seems to be a permissions issue -- some of my colleagues are able to do this.  Here are the steps I'm attempting in SSMS.Select dbName;
Right click select Tasks;
Select Generate Scripts;
Next;
Select radio button that enable you to choose what you want to generate;
Expand tables;
Check tables desired;
Next;
Bottom radio button to make a new query;
Click Advanced;
Change Include descriptions to False;
Set option to CREATE scripts;
OK;
Next; error message that Script Generation Failed.  Click Help for Known Solutions (clicking Help shows nothing relevant)
